# Audio CDROM not playing properly on new Install

Tags: sound, dvd-audio

Ubuntu Friends,
Please help me get my USB audio CDROM/DVD to play properly.  It plays through speakers but stops for a second or so frequently and takes 30 – 60- seconds to start each track.
Hardware:

- HP Desktop model 251-130xt (10 years old?)
- LG USB CDROM/DVD writer, model GP63EX70
- Verbatim CDROM/DVD writer, model 98938
- Both players behave the same: sound stops for a second or so repeatedly, and it takes 30 – 60 seconds to start each track.
  Software:
- Ubuntu 23.10 newly installed
- Installed “All the essential media codecs” by installing "Ubuntu Restricted Extras" with instructions from itsfoss.com.  No change in the behavior.
  Any ideas?
  Thank you,  RichG

Comment: Oh, I'm playing the tracks with the latest version of VLC.  Thanks.